# Is SOQL Polymorphism also supported in WHERE clause?

Tags: apex, soql, query, polymorphism

I am using the polymorphism in my SOQL queries which is working fine, an generic example of the query is below

```
SELECT 
    TYPEOF What 
        WHEN Account THEN Phone, NumberOfEmployees 
        WHEN Opportunity THEN Amount, CloseDate 
        ELSE Name, Email 
    END 
FROM Event
```

Now if i want to only query all the Event associated to all accounts which have a phone number of '123456', is that possible? I would need to use polymorphic fields in my where condition. I am trying the syntax but i am getting issues, not very sure if we can use polymorphism in where condition. What i am trying to get is something like this but is not working

> SELECT TYPEOF What WHEN Account THEN Phone, NumberOfEmployees WHEN
>   Opportunity THEN Amount, CloseDate ELSE Name, Email END FROM Event
>   where TYPEOF What WHEN Account THEN Phone Else Name END ='123456'

Comment: I suspect you'll have to use an uglier: `where whatid in (select id from account where phone = '123456') or whatid in (select id from opportunity where name = '123456')`

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox but you couldnt use right outer join for whatId field. Dont you get a error when you execute the above SQOL

Answer (score 5):

Based on the current [TYPEOF](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) documentation that clause is only applicable within the SELECT statement.

> TYPEOF is an optional clause **that can be used in a SELECT statement of a SOQL query** when you’re querying data that contains polymorphic relationships.

You might need to use something like `What.Type = 'Account' and What.Phone = '123456'` in the SOQL query. Maybe build it up with some additional conditions.

E.g.

```
SELECT ID, WhatId 
FROM Event 
WHERE 
    (What.Type = 'Account' and What.Phone = '12345') or 
    (What.Type = 'Campaign' and What.Name = '12345')
```

Oddly, as @Anil observes in the comments, other Account fields produce an error:

```
SELECT ID, WhatId, What.Type
FROM Event 
WHERE 
    (What.Type = 'Account' and What.BillingCity = '12345')
```

gives:

> INVALID_FIELD:
>     (What.Type = 'Account' and What.BillingCity = '12345')
>   ERROR at Row:4:Column:36
>   No such column 'BillingCity' on entity 'Name'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

I suspect the `What.Type = 'Account'` guard statement isn't preventing the column checking on the polymorphic What field.

I was going to suggest that if all the types referenced by the field have the field being checked then the filter will work and if the field only belongs to a subset of the types they you will get the error. However, this doesn't appear to be the case either, as Campaign doesn't have a Phone field.

Comment: Note, I didn't have enough Event data loaded in my test org to verify the proposed SOQL query returns the required results. It does however execute without an error.

Comment: Thats very unfortunate that we dont polymorphism in the where clause, Using WHAT.Phone helps but it doesnt work on all account fields , if you try What.BillingCity doesnt not work. I am not sure how only few fields like name, phone etc are working for what.FIELDNAME